# Why is $ProcessorCount not equal to LaunchKernels[ ]?

Tags: parallelization

Normally, number of `$ProcessorCount` should be the same as `LaunchKernels[]`, but if they are not the same, what is the problem?

[image]

---

**Update**

I just tried to manually launch kernel as this

```
LaunchKernels[24]
```

And test parallel computation, surprisingly, it indeed use 24 cores at the same time

[image]

Than why `$ConfiguredKernels` is 16 by default? I tried setting `$ConfiguredKernels=24`, but `LaunchKernels[]` still gives 16 kernels. What is wrong?

Comment: You may want to check your `$ConfiguredKernels` value, as well as the configuration in Preferences -> Parallel -> Local Kernels. The licensing limitations will of course depend on the actual license being used.

Comment: @ilian You are right. `$ConfiguredKernels` shows 16. But what does this mean "The licensing limitations will of course depend on the actual license being used.“? $MaxLicenseSubprocesses shows infinity

Comment: You are probably using a *MathLM* license server, so you can launch as many kernels as you like, as long as there are network licenses available for them; [monitorlm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MonitoringMathLM.html) can be used to query the server for the number of authorized/available/in use processes.

Comment: @ilian I didn't install MathLM. So I think this may not be the right point.

Comment: @ilian I add new phenomena in the post

Comment: Maybe check whether `$LicenseServer` returns the same as your  `$MachineName` just to be sure.

Comment: @ilian yeah, they are the same

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why the infinite value then. Can you set your desired number of kernels in Preferences -> Parallel -> Local Kernels? In case this is actually a problem, I would suggest getting in touch with technical support with your license information.

Comment: @ilian well, I don't know how to set ` Preferences -> Parallel -> Local Kernels` with command line. I can't launch graphic interface on HPC, only command line

Comment: You can set `$ConfiguredKernels={SubKernels\`LocalKernels\`LocalMachine[24]};`

Comment: @ilian This seems not a permanent solution. Restart mma, the setting is gone. I just come up with an idea that I can simply add `LaunchKernels[$ProcessorCount]` in my code

Comment: @matheorem, did you fully solve this issue. I have the same issue that I am only launching 16 kernels despite the fact that on my hpc it says that `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses=Infinity` I see that you conclude that by using `LaunchKernels[24]` you  are able to launch all 24 kernels and use them? 

I just tried and was surprised to find that even on my laptop it seems to be able to launch 32 kernels as well despite the fact that I only have `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses==16` here (nor do I have that many cores).

Answer (score 4):

Your license may only allow 16 subkernels.  You can check this by evaluating

```
$MaxLicenseSubprocesses
```

Comment: Well, it is actually infinity...

Comment: @matheorem Well, what happens if you try to launch more than 16?

Comment: Yeah, I just feel confused about that. No matter on my laptop or on HPC, if I run LaunchKernels[num], num greater than processorcount, It will give a kernel list of exactly num, I don't understand what does that mean.